# SQLAlchemy / gevent / cx_Oracle pool size stays at 1

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, gevent

I cannot get SQLAlchemy v. 1.3.22 with gevent 21.1.2 and cx_Oracle 8.1.0 to issue more than one query at a time despite the fact that I use a pool size of 50.

I am not sure which of the libraries it is more about hence my adding all of the tags that seemed applicable.

I confirmed that my user can establish more than one connection to the Oracle database - I have another program where I can easily run 50 queries in parallel using the same credentials and database.

I invoke the code below using siege - no matter what concurrency I set, I always get a single connection in the pool.

As soon as I remove the SQLAlchemy-related code from the 'application' handler, siege reports the expected concurrency of 50 which I understand means that it is in fact running that many concurrent connections at a time.

I understand that SQLAlchemy establishes new connections on demand but I do not understand why it is not doing it here as clearly there is demand.

```py
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
patch_all()

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

username = '<hidden>'
password = '<hidden>'
host = '<hidden>'
port = '<hidden>'
database = '<hidden>'

url = 'oracle://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(username, password, host, port, database)

engine = create_engine(url, pool_size=50)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def application(env, start_response):

    session = Session()
    result = session.execute('select 1+1 from dual')
    result.fetchall()
    session.close()

    print('Status:', engine.pool.status())

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [b'<b>hello world</b>']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Serving on 8088...')
    WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8088), application, log=None).serve_forever()
```

Siege:

```
siege -r 500 -c 50 http://localhost:8088/

Transactions:                 31 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               4.13 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:              2.60 secs
Transaction rate:           7.51 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:               19.50
Successful transactions:          31
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            4.10
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Output from the server:

```
Status: Pool size: 50  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -49 Current Checked out connections: 0
Status: Pool size: 50  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -49 Current Checked out connections: 0
Status: Pool size: 50  Connections in pool: 1 Current Overflow: -49 Current Checked out connections: 0
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think yor problem arises from the fact that cx_oracle is not naturally "green". So it can't start green threats and therefore can't run multiple queries at a time. Take a look at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/126

Answer (score 0):

Add in the top

```
import greenify

greenify.greenify()
assert greenify.patch_lib("/usr/lib/oracle/19.5/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1")
```

but adjust the pool size otherwise yo are risking your application getting killed the hard way. You need to test it first which your question provides an excellent script for. See https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/126