# What does the error KPEDBG_HDL_PUSH_FCPTRMAX mean?

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to combine cx_oracle, sqlalchemy and gevent using [SQLAlchemy / gevent / cx_Oracle pool size stays at 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959615/sqlalchemy-gevent-cx-oracle-pool-size-stays-at-1) and https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/126
When I allow cx_oracle to run in parallel I can create many connections. Acturaly I can create so many that in the end I kill my connection "KPEDBG_HDL_PUSH_FCPTRMAX" witch I guess is a throttling expection. But does anybody know what this error is indicating?

Comment: No idea. But, maybe this (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6197) means something to you.

Comment: Share some code and absolute numbers.  Are you actually starting the cx_Oracle session pool with threaded mode?  Have you looked for Oracle "client" trace files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have data structures in your Database which is protected. If you have concurrent accesses by multiple threads in this structure this failure will be raised.